# sql multiple columns filtering duplicates by newest

Tags: mysql, sqlite, filter, tuples, multiple-columns

I have a SQL query (sqlight3) that gives me tripels (name, value, date) of data.

```
select name, value, date from
"different things and conditions"
order by date desc
```

The result ist sorted by date and looks like this:

```
name | value | date
-------------------
a    | x     | 2015
b    | y     | 2014
a    | z     | 2013
b    | x     | 2012
c    | y     | 2011
```

Now I want the results filtered, so that every name is unique and I only get the newest (by date) triples. I expect the result

```
name | value | date
-------------------
a    | x     | 2015
b    | y     | 2014
c    | y     | 2011
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Taged it with mysql, thanks.

Comment: noticed that was wrong, sorry. Meant sqlight3.

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support ANSI standard window functions, so this can be done using `row_number()`:

```
select name, value, date
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by date desc) as seqnum
      from . . .
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

MySQL doesn't support `row_number()`.  Here is another method:

```
select name,
       substring_index(group_concat(value order by date desc), ',', 1) as value
       max(date) as date
from . . .
group by name;
```

Comment: Looks like mysql3 doesn't support "row_number()" and "parition", sorry.

Comment: I am sorry to ask, but do you happen to know something for sqlight3, too? Substring_index doesn't exist there.